# How to set active tab via jQuery select where tab content is outside of ul element?

Tags: jquery, tabs

After page load I want to programmatically set the active tab...in the example below I want to set tab with English as active.

I tried:

```
$('#languagetabs').tabs('select', 1);
```

and

```
$('.edittabs').tabs('select', 1);
```

But that did not work, as in nothing happens: no error, and the 1st tab remains active.

```
<div class="edittabs">
    <ul id="languagetabs">
        <li><a href="#language-spanish">Spanish</a></li>
        <li><a href="#language-english">English</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="language-spanish">        
        Spanish description
    </div>
    <div id="language-english">
        English description
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#languagetabs li:eq(1) a').trigger('click');
```

This will emulate the 2nd tab being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class active ,

```
.active{background:#5d5d5d;}

<li><a href="#language-english" class="active">English</a></li>

$('#languagetabs li').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

hope it will help you..

Comment: My tabs already work correctly. My question is how I can programmatically switch to another tab.